# R - changing date's order

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe (dat), with a "date" variable, which is in the format of `dd.mm.yyyy` (example: 31.12.2022)

1. I would like to know how could I reverse it to `yyyy.mm.dd`?
2. I also tried to separate `d`, `m`, and `y`, so that I could re-merge them in a different column, but I am facing problems with this.

```
dat2 <- separate(data = dat,
                 col = "date", 
                 sep = ".", 
                 into = c("session_day","session_month", "session_year"))
```

which is giving this message

> Warning message: Expected 3 pieces.
> Additional pieces discarded in 1566 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
> 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...].

I appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: Just convert to `Date` and use `format` i.e. `format(as.Date("31.12.2022", "%d.%m.%Y"), "%Y.%m.%d")` with your column, it is `as.Date(dat$date, "%d.%m.%Y")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like what you already tried and think you can continue with that. Casting the column to a date first and using `format` to rearrange it as you wish as mentioned in the comments is definetely the best way to approach this problem, but I would like to explain why you are getting that error message when trying it your way:

You are getting the error message because the `sep` argument in tidyr::seperate needs a regular expression. You are using `sep = "."` right now, but a `.` is a special character in regular expressions, meaning any character.

If you want to match a dot you will need to escape it using `\\.`

This should work for you and then move on from there.

```
dat2 <- separate(data = dat, 
                 col = "date", 
                 sep = "\\.", 
                 into = c("session_day","session_month", "session_year"))
```